# Do any automated theorem provers have the ability to stop, save state, reboot computer, restore state, continue?

Tags: automated-theorem-proving

With automated theorem provers knowing ahead of time how long the search will take or even if it will find a solution is unknown. Often for long running searches one eventually just has to halt the process and loose all work up to that point.

Do any automated theorem provers or proof assistants with automated search have the ability to stop, save the state, allow the computer to be rebooted, restore the saved state and continue the search as if the process was only temporarily idled and then allowed to continue?

The reason a reboot was noted is that sometimes such means will fail after a reboot. Finding out the hard way is painful.

Another more elaborate scenario that could be needed is the search is started on a desktop, after several hours it is saved and restored into a cloud server. If that is possible the answer should note that.

Answers need to show in supported versions of the application's documentation how this is done. If the feature use to work and no longer works that will not be considered an answer. If the feature is an experimental feature then that will not be considered an answer. If the software has not been updated in the last two years that would be considered unsupported and not be an acceptable answer. [Seeds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed) are not considered an acceptable answer.

---

Side notes:

For applications that do not have this feature two possible work arounds.

1. [Docker Checkpoint & Restore](https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/1d20b15adc382c9be213a45fdd846038cd984a0e/experimental/checkpoint-restore.md) - Requires running in a Docker container.
2. [VMWare Suspend and Resume](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/16.0/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-A4536112-10A6-4574-ADE5-60D9BBAE1F02.html) - Requires running in VMWare virtual machine.

Comment: This is a really interesting question. I wonder if there are any automated theorem provers that (can) use a SQLite database or something similar to keep track of dead ends in the search space.

Comment: Coq versions 8.13 and earlier had `-inputstate` and `-outputstate` command-line arguments and `Write State` and `Restore State` commands.  The `-inputstate` argument was [removed for Coq 8.14](https://github.com/coq/coq/pull/13822), and the other three were [removed for Coq 8.15](https://github.com/coq/coq/pull/14940).  It seems these options and commands were never documented in the reference manual, though they appeared in the help text.  Posting as a comment rather than an answer because (a) Coq is an ITP not an ATP, and (b) it doesn't meet a bunch of your criteria for an acceptable answer.

Comment: @JasonGross Thanks. I agree that I would not accept it as an answer because it is no longer in the current version.

Comment: @JasonGross As for the tag I used, as we don't have a tag that focuses on just the automated search part of provers I just used the current one. If you can think of a new tag such that it will not be misused I would consider changing the tag here.